# Get data for 3 particular dates in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I know this code is wrong the input should be like this how to give 3 dates

```
select Factory,Sum(quantity) from table where date='23-09-2017' and date='24-09-2017' and date='25-09-2017 group by factory
```

Comment: Replace `and` with `or`. Or explain in more detail what you are trying to do

Comment: dude i want the sum of quantity for the factories on 3 particular date
like 1 column will be factory name and other 3 columns will be quantity of 3 given dates..

Comment: So you want to pivot as well? Please edit your question to add sample data and expected output.

Comment: What is type of [date] column?

Answer (score 0):

select Factory,Sum(quantity) from table where date IN ('23-09-2017','24-09-2017','25-09-2017') group by factory

Comment: Error: Conversion of varchar data type to a date time data type resulted in out of range value

Answer (score 0):

This is can be done using `BETWEEN`, `OR` and `IN`.

**Query**

**`Using BETWEEN`**

```
select Factory, 
Sum(quantity) 
from table 
where [date] between '23-09-2017' and date='25-09-2017'
group by factory;
```

Can be used `BETWEEN` because your dates are three consecutive dates.

**`Using OR`**

```
select Factory, 
Sum(quantity) 
from table 
where date='23-09-2017' or date='24-09-2017' or date='25-09-2017'
group by factory;
```

**`Using IN`**

```
select Factory, 
Sum(quantity) 
from table 
where date in ('23-09-2017','24-09-2017','25-09-2017')
group by factory;
```

Comment: how to use cast for that date for using in

Comment: @Sasank : So, are you storing dates as `varchar`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try 'in' if the dates do not fall in range or use between if the dates are between a range.

```
select Factory, Sum(quantity) from table1 
WHERE Convert(Date, datefield) in '2017-09-23','2017-09-24','2017-09-25')
group by Factory

select Factory, Sum(quantity) from table1 
where Convert(Date, datefield)between '2017-09-23' and '2017-09-25'
group by Factory
```

Comment: errro :conversion failed when converting date or time from character string

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this :

```
select Factory,
       SUM( CASE WHEN date='23-09-2017' THEN quantity END) '23-09-2017'
       SUM( CASE WHEN date='24-09-2017' THEN quantity END) '24-09-2017'
       SUM( CASE WHEN date='25-09-2017' THEN quantity END) '25-09-2017' 
from table 
group by factory
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date1 datetime,
@date2 datetime,
@date3 datetime

select @date1 = '2017-09-24',@date2 = '2017-09-30',@date3 = '2017-03-31'

select Fac 'Particular',
sum(case when cast(tran_date as date ) =  cast(@date1 as date ) then Qty 
else 0 end ) AS '@date1',
sum(case when cast(tran_date as date ) =  cast(@date2 as date ) then Qty 
else 0 end  )AS '@date2',
sum(case when cast(tran_date as date ) =  cast(@date3 as date ) then Qty 
else 0 end  )AS '@date3'
from [table] where (cast(tran_date as date ) =  cast(@date1 as date )
OR cast(tran_date as date ) =  cast(@date2 as date )
OR cast(tran_date as date ) =  cast(@date3 as date ))
group by fac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT Factory,
       SUM(quantity)
FROM   Table
WHERE YEAR(date)  = 2017
  AND MONTH(date) = 09
  AND DAY(date) IN (23, 24, 25)
GROUP BY Factory
```

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 0):

When you call specific date in sql like '20170922' it will search for 22 09 2017 00:00 time so you should use BETWEEN in your query. Expected query should look like;

```
Select SUM(quantity),Datepart(day,Date),Factory 
FROM table 
Where (Date BETWEEN '2017-09-23' AND '2017-09-24') 
                 OR (Date BETWEEN '2017-09-24' AND '2017-09-25') 
Group By Factory ,DATEPART(day,Date)
```